# Custom domain name of SharePoint 2013 app

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, domain

Let's say our SharePoint 2013 online url is `https://someorg-public.sharepoint.com`

Is it possible to add a subsite (like an application under IIS website) that launches a SharePoint app?

I created a sample SharePoint 2013 app in Visual Studio and deployed it to SharePoint online, and got a long isolated url like `https://someorg-ba340f7a7fce61.sharepoint.com/mySharePointApp`

I'm wondering if the app can be accessed under the same root domain as shown in the picture below, something like `https://someorg-public.sharepoint.com/mySharePointApp`.

If this is not possible, how are users supposed to access the app? Like the developer provides the isolated domain link to the app in a page?

And how do I set the master page of the app page to the master page being used on SharePoint online?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**URL**: The App Model depends on the fact that each App has it's own domain. This ensures that Apps are isolated from the host SharePoint site collection and from other Apps. It also helps prevent cross-site scripting.

**Link to access App**: Users access an App the way they would access a List or Library, from a link in Site Contents.

**Master page**: Even though the have a unique domain name, SharePoint-Hosted Apps are actually just sub-sites of the site where the App was installed. So, the pages in the App automatically uses the master page of its host site collection.

Comment: Rob, thanks for providing a clean answer. I now realize I cannot use routing style app with this deployment model (SharePoint hosted) partially because of the URL scheme. Too bad we have to maintain 2 SharePoint instances just for routing.

Comment: Most useful link I've found so far: SharePoint public website feature being replaced by GoDaddy and Wix: http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/3027254